# DDMS FileExplorer contents visibility beyond eclipse IDE

Tags: android, eclipse, ddms

Other than Eclipse DDMS File Explorer where I can see those(i.e mnt,data,system)  folder and files,So i can do modify easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use `adb shell` command to browse files of the device/emulator from command prompt or terminal

by issueing `adb shell` command on your command prompt you can starts a remote shell in the target emulator/device. And you dont need to broswe files from the `eclipse FileExplorer` view.

Suppose you want to broswe `data` directory then use this command:

`adb shell ls /data`

[image: result of the command adb shell ls /data]

Note: you can find `adb` in `<sdk>\platform-tools\` or `<sdk>\tools\`

Refer [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#shellcommands) for more information.

Comment: ok.. which is the best folder here to place our temporary application data?

Comment: @vnshetty: These are the system speciefic folders and I would recommend you should store temporary data in the `/sdcard/` directory.